# Is the function of a ring always non-empty?

Tags: ring-theory

I was wondering if, for example, we have a function $f(R)$ which maps all elements from the ring $R$ to another ring $S$, would the set which contains all elements mapped to $S$ be non-empty? This is because in the notes I took in one of my Algebra classes, where we had to prove that the set of the mapped elements is a also sub-ring, my professor wrote the following in order to initially prove that this set is not empty:

$f(R)\neq 0$ because $0_S \in f(R)$.

Comment: You seem to be missing something about the types of functions we are considering and are misnaming the function.  The function is likely supposed to be named $f$.  Not $f(R)$, that is the range, not the function.  As it is written, yes any function (*when viewed as a set*) which is a map between rings must be non-empty... because for instance we would have $f(0_R)$ needs to be mapped to something and so by the very definition of a function we must have some pair $(0_R, s)$ as an element of $f$ for some $s\in S$.  It is not necessary however for $0_S$ to be in the range of $f$ as it is written.

Comment: Now... if we knew more about $f$, such as that it is an isomorphism or homomorphism... then yes we *could* say that $0_S\in f(R)$ since we would be able to know for instance that $f(0_R)=0_S$ among other things.  Without such a condition however we can say very little.  As an example, taking the usual ring of reals $(\Bbb R,+,\cdot)$ the function $f~:~\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=2$ for all $x$... we clearly have the range of $f$ is just $\{2\}$ and does not contain zero.